# SQL Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=AS;FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY);), DRIVER=3.57.82

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, prepared-statement

The below DB2 stored procedure compiled successfully but getting runtime error `SQL Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=AS;FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY);), DRIVER=3.57.82`

Intention of the below db2 procedure is to delete the records from multiple tables with prepared statements.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ALL_DATA_PURGE1(IN v_SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(24),IN v_DAYS INTEGER, IN v_COMMIT_COUNT INTEGER)
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN

    -- DECLARE Statements
    DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER;

    DECLARE v_CRAD_DELETE_QUERY    VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE v_APPDATA_DELETE_QUERY VARCHAR(1024);

    DECLARE v_CRAD_DELETE_STATEMENT STATEMENT;
    DECLARE v_APPDATA_DELETE_STATEMENT STATEMENT;

    SET v_CRAD_DELETE_QUERY = 'DELETE FROM (SELECT 1 FROM ' || v_SCHEMA_NAME || '.CRAD WHERE UNIQUE_ID IN  
    (SELECT UNIQUE_ID FROM  ' || v_SCHEMA_NAME || '.APPDATA WHERE ORIGINATOR_TIMESTAMP < (
      SELECT CURRENT TIMESTAMP - '|| v_DAYS ||' DAYS FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
      ) FETCH FIRST ' || v_COMMIT_COUNT || ' ROWS ONLY) AS DELETE_CRAD_TABLE';      

    SET v_APPDATA_DELETE_QUERY = 'DELETE FROM (SELECT 1 FROM ' || v_SCHEMA_NAME || '.APPDATA WHERE SOME_TIMESTAMP < (
      SELECT CURRENT TIMESTAMP - ' || v_DAYS || ' days FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
      ) FETCH FIRST ' || v_COMMIT_COUNT || ' ROWS ONLY) AS DELETE_APPDATA_TABLE';


    PREPARE v_CRAD_DELETE_STATEMENT    FROM v_CRAD_DELETE_QUERY;  
    PREPARE v_APPDATA_DELETE_STATEMENT FROM v_APPDATA_DELETE_QUERY;

    DELETE_LOOP:
        LOOP
            EXECUTE v_CRAD_DELETE_STATEMENT;
            EXECUTE v_APPDATA_DELETE_STATEMENT;

            IF SQLCODE = 100 THEN
                LEAVE DELETE_LOOP; 
            END IF;
            COMMIT;
        END LOOP;

   COMMIT;

END
```

Comment: please edit the question, so that the stored procedure is shown entirely as code

Answer (score 1):

The Stored Procedure compiles because the dynamic SQL statements are not known. At runtime DB2 notices that you are not following its syntax rules. The statements look overly complicated and could be simplified. You don't need to select from sysdummy1 - some simple expressions would do.

Did you test the individual statements before composing the stored procedure?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did test individually and it's working. Please suggest me how to simplify these complex queries.

Comment: All syntax error are resolved and I need to simplify now.

Comment: An example: get rid of the "(select ... from sysdummy1)" - it is a simple "(current timestamp - v_Days DAYS)"

Comment: Thanks that is done and working. Which approach is best to delete huge data from the tables either through cursor(my other question which I posted) or prepared statement like the above one.

Comment: For deleting large chunks of data based on date/time properties, tables often are range partitioned. In that case only the qualifying partitions get detached. Have you looked into that? What are the day ranges for your application?

Comment: My stored proc is working, but I have to see the best performance where I have two options to delete large chunks of data one is through cursor and another one is using the prepared statement. Please let me know which is is better for my requirement.